# Using JQuery datepicker: default date isn't saved in the field until the icon is selected

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a web form with a 'from' date and a 'to' date. Both use the jQuery datepicker, with the 'from' date defaulting to today and the 'to' date defaulting to tomorrow.

If I just accept the defaults, the 'from' date is correctly recorded in the database but the 'to' date is simply recorded as "00/00/0000". However, if I use the calendar widget to actually set a date, then it works fine.

Here is my code for the two datepickers (just called datepicker1 and datepicker2 for now):

```
  $("#datepicker1").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                    showOn: "button",
                    buttonImage: "images/15.gif",
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    autoSize: true,
                                minDate: 0,
                                onSelect: function(dateText,picker) {
                                $('#day').val( dateText.split(/\//)[0] );
                                $('#month').val( dateText.split(/\//)[1] );
                                $('#year').val( dateText.split(/\//)[2] );
                                } 
                              });
 $("#datepicker2").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                    showOn: "button",
                    buttonImage: "images/15.gif",
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    autoSize: true,
                                minDate: 0,
                                onSelect: function(dateText,picker) {
                                $('#exp_day').val( dateText.split(/\//)[0] );
                                $('#exp_month').val( dateText.split(/\//)[1] );
                                $('#exp_year').val( dateText.split(/\//)[2] );
                                } 
                              });
 $('#datepicker1').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
 $('#datepicker2').datepicker('setDate', '+1d')
```

And my two input fields are simply:

```
<input id="datepicker1" class="datepicker" />
<input id="datepicker2" class="datepicker" />
```

So far, the only thing I have checked is the format of the fields in the database, but they are identical. Which leans me to think this is a problem with how I have set up the datepickers.

Any pointers to how I can fix this? Thanks everyone.

Comment: which datepicker is which? Is #DatePicker1 your "to" and #DatePicker2 the "from" field?

Comment: Datepicker1="From", Datepicker2="To"

Answer (score 0):

I think this  will  help you out

```
var datepicker2 = $('#datepicker1').datepicker('getDate', '+1d'); 
 $('#datepicker2 ').datepicker('setDate', datepicker2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately this made no difference. It works, in terms of populating the second field with a default date, but the results aren't being posted to the database. I managed to check the field contents through the DOM and it is showing the correct date.